# creating subplots for lag_plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i want to plot 2 `lag_plot`s by using `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`. here is my code:

### 1.Grab Data

```py
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# start date
start = f"{date.today().year-3}-{date.today().month}-{date.today().day}"

# end date
end = date.today()

# 'MSFT' data
MSFT = pd.DataFrame(web.DataReader('MSFT' , start=start , end=end ,data_source='yahoo')['Close'])


# 'S&P 500' data
s_and_p500 = pd.DataFrame(web.DataReader('sp500' , start=start , end=end ,data_source='fred'))
```

### 2.Making Plots

```py
fig , (ax1 , ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1)
fig.set_figheight(4)
fig.set_figwidth(20)

ax1 = pd.plotting.lag_plot(MSFT['Close'])
ax2 = pd.plotting.lag_plot(s_and_p500['sp500'])
```

output:
[image]

as you can see, `plt` is plotting both in 1! I mean the area that I denoted in picture, is for this `ax2 = pd.plotting.lag_plot(s_and_p500['sp500'])` part of the code! but `plt` should put each of `ax1 , ax2` in separated figures (first figure shouldn't be empty)!
How can I fix this?

Comment: you can specify the Axes to use as an argument: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.plotting.lag_plot.html?highlight=lag_plot

Comment: @PaulH can you make an example and post it as an answer?

Comment: The answer you linked to does this

Comment: **I've seen this question before, but it doesn't help me with this.** your accepted answer is the same as in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work ?

```
from pandas.tools.plotting import lag_plot
lag_plot(MSFT['Close'], ax = ax1)
lag_plot(s_and_p500['sp500'], ax = ax2)
```